# Issue with accessing Google Analytics data with Javascript and API

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-analytics

I am trying to get from Google Analytics the number of visitors (users) to our website, preferably with Javascript.

I already setup a project and credentials in Google to work with my employer's Google Analytics, and was able to get the javascript example that generates a chart to work correctly.

However what I need is the text data for the metrics and not a chart generated, so that I can include the data in my employers ASP.NET MVC C# web application.

The chart example, like the text data example, uses an authentication button where I can enter the login and password for my employers google analytics, this works correctly for the chart example and also appears to work correctly with the text example, but the text example is not generating data when I run it.

I found an example at this URL to generate text data from Google Analytics, but it only generates errors when I run it.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js

Here is my source code that I am using, in a single HTML file, if there is an error please point it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello Analytics Reporting API V4</title>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxxxxxx">
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello Analytics Reporting API V4</h1>

<p>
    <!-- The Sign-in button. This will run `queryReports()` on success. -->
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="queryReports"></div>
</p>

<!-- The API response will be printed here. -->
<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea>

<script>
// Replace with your view ID.
var VIEW_ID = '132296038';

// Query the API and print the results to the page.
function queryReports() {
  gapi.client.request({
    path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
    root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      "reportRequests": [
        {
          "viewId": VIEW_ID,
          "dateRanges": [
          {
            "startDate": "2017-02-01",
            "endDate": "2017-03-16"
          }
        ],
        "metrics": [
          {
            "expression": "ga:sessions"
          }
        ],
        "dimensions": [
            { "name": "ga:date" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
    // }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
}).then(displayResults, alert(console.error.toString()));
}

function displayResults(response) {
  var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
  document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
}
</script>

<!-- Load the JavaScript API client and Sign-in library. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, so in my opinion you are using bad client_id, view_id, you have not enabled Google Analytics Reporting API or your host is not accepted by API server.

What error message do you get? Your error reporting function do not report anything usable for me, so I recommend changing:

```
alert(console.error.toString())
```

to:

```
function (error) { alert(error.result.error.message); }
```

Please post full error message for further help.

Comment: Is it possible to use the login into analytics without pressing the button 'g-signin2'? I mean, start automatically the google login on window load and them make a request.